# update DIV with external file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a external file with text inside then that is update everytime.

```
<div id='1'>TEST 1</div>
<div id='2'>TEST 2</div>
<div id='3'>TEST 3</div>
```

This archive is called `IO.HTML`, My Script is getting all the information inside this archive and putting then in only one div, with all the information, I want to separated and update the specific ID every second, with only the text inside it, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("IO.html", function(result){
        $('#1').text(result.trim());
        $('#2').text(result.trim());
        $('#3').text(result.trim());
    });
},1000);
});
```

html:

```
<div class="Takt" id="1"></div>
<div class="Takt" id="2"></div>
<div class="Takt" id="3"></div>
```

But how I say, in the `ID 1`, all the information in the archive `IO.html` is writing inside then, How can I separated this information with only the text inside the ID?

Comment: Use `$IO = $('<div>').html(result);`. Now you can get the text using `$IO.find('div').eq(i).text()` where `i` is the index (0, 1 or 2). Loop over your existing divs, and you have your `i`.

Comment: I think I'm writing in the wrong place the function, the console returns for me this : 'Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined' , can you plis write the hole JS with this code that you provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `result` in `$()` so you can use jQuery methods to extract the relevant parts of it the same wy you would

```
$.get("IO.html", function(result){
     const $doc = $(result);
     $.each([1,2,3], function(_, n){
        // use `filter()` instead of `find()` if the elements are not 
        // in a wrapping container
        $('#' + n).html( $doc.find('#' + n).html())
     });     
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

To load the appropriate content use:

```
$('#1').load('IO.html #1');
```

Therefore to load all the three `div`s use:

```
[1,2,3].map(a => $('#' + a).load('IO.html #' + a));
```

**REFERENCE**

- [.load() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Numeric id's are valid in html5

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, let me make some edits to that effect.